# swift cursor position with emojis

Tags: swift, string, emoji, cursor-position

The standard method I use to get the cursor position in a UITextfield does not seem to work with some emojis.  The following code queries a textField for cursor position after insertion of two characters, first an emoji and then a letter character.  When the emoji is inserted into the textField the function returns a value of 2 for the cursor position instead of the expected result of 1.  Any ideas into what I am doing wrong or how to correct this.  Thanks

Here is the code from an xcode playground:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

override func loadView() {
    //setup view
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
    textField.textColor = .black
    view.addSubview(textField)
    self.view = view

    //check cursor position
    var str = ""
    textField.insertText(str)
    print("cursor position after '\(str)' insertion is \(getCursorPosition(textField))")

    textField.text = ""
    str = "A"
    textField.insertText(str)
     print("cursor position after '\(str)' insertion is \(getCursorPosition(textField))")
}

func getCursorPosition(_ textField: UITextField) -> Int {
    if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
        let cursorPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.end)
        return cursorPosition
    }
    return -1
}
```

}

the code return the following output:

```
cursor position after '' insertion is 2
cursor position after 'A' insertion is 1
```

I'm trying to use the cursor position to split the text string into two pieces -- the text that occurs before the cursor and the text that occurs after the cursor. To do this I use the cursor position as an index for a character array I have created using the map function as follows.  The cursor position leads to an incorrect array index with an emoji

```
    var textBeforeCursor = String()
    var textAfterCursor = String()
    let array = textField.text!.map { String($0) }
    let cursorPosition = getCursorPosition(textField)
    for index in 0..<cursorPosition {
        textBeforeCursor += array[index]
    }
```

Comment: Some emoji letters consist of two unicode characters.  Some consist of three unicode characters.  There many emoji letters that consist of four unicode characters as well.

Comment: yes but I'm running into problems when I try to use the cursor position to split the text into two pieces.  I will edit the question to make things more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that the `NSRange` value returned by `UITextField selectedTextRange` and the `offset` need to be properly converted to a Swift `String.Index`.

```
func getCursorPosition(_ textField: UITextField) -> String.Index? {
    if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
        let cursorPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.end)
        let positionRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: cursorPosition)
        let stringOffset = Range(positionRange, in: textField.text!)!

        return stringOffset.upperBound
    }

    return nil
}
```

Once you have that `String.Index` you can split the string.

```
if let index = getCursorPosition(textField) {
    let textBeforeCursor = textField.text![..<index]
    let textAfterCursor = textField.text![index...]
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reason why this worked. I tried to debug every line, but somehow failed to understand why `positionRange` played a major role.

Comment: @Dennis In short, the `selectedTextRange` property of `UITextField` is based on the UTF-16 encoding of the string. That needs to be converted to a Swift `String.Index` which is based on character count.

Comment: Ahh makes sense, I was thinking the same.. just wanted to confirm. Thanks for the revert :)

Comment: I used the above code,
Input : `abc<emoji><emoji><emoji>|cd [cursor position is before “cd”]`
Expected result : Text before cursor :  `abc<emoji><emoji><emoji>`
Actual result : Text before cursor : `abc<junk character><emoji><emoji>`
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I used your code to delete characters from 'textBeforeCursor' but it looks like the cursor is getting set after deleting single character to the end of the string. Do you have any hint how i can maintain the position of the cursor?